# MiKTeX - broken package combination fontspec / expl3

Tags: luatex, miktex, fontspec, expl3

I have some problems after installing the latest 64bit-MiKTeX as well as the latest packages through the package manager. It seems that there is a problem with the combination of `fontspec` and `expl3` from the `l3kernel`. I read about errors with newer version of `fontspec` in combination with `expl3` and had a look at different workarounds, but I think that this one is different.

The log is below.

Any hint is welcome!

Bye Holger

`LuaTeX:` beta-0.80.0 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (rev 5238)

`l3kernel, l3packages etc:` packaged on 2015-11-05

complete log file: http://pastebin.com/VU2DJEqG

example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{fontspec}

% workaround for suppressfontnotfounderror
\ifdefined\suppressfontnotfounderror
  \expandafter\let\csname xetex_suppressfontnotfounderror:D\endcsname
    \suppressfontnotfounderror
\else
  \expandafter\let\csname xetex_suppressfontnotfounderror:D\endcsname
    \luatexsuppressfontnotfounderror
\fi


\newfontfamily{\Arial}
[Ligatures=TeX,UprightFont=arial.ttf]{arial}

\begin{document}
\Arial Some text in Arial...

\rmfamily Some text in regular font...

\end{document}
```

some of the errors:

```
Undefined control sequence. ...\c_e_fp { 2.718 2818 2845 9045 }
Undefined control sequence. ...\c_e_fp { 2.718 2818 2845 9045 }
LuaTeX error [\directlua]:1: invalid escape sequence near '\s'. ...\c_e_fp { 2.718 2818 2845 9045 }
Missing number, treated as zero. ...\c_e_fp { 2.718 2818 2845 9045 }
Undefined control sequence. \fp_const:Nn \c_one_fp { 1 }
Undefined control sequence. \fp_const:Nn \c_one_fp { 1 }
LuaTeX error [\directlua]:1: invalid escape sequence near '\s'. \fp_const:Nn \c_one_fp { 1 }
Missing number, treated as zero. \fp_const:Nn \c_one_fp { 1 }
Undefined control sequence. ...\c_pi_fp { 3.141 5926 5358 9793 }
Undefined control sequence. ...\c_pi_fp { 3.141 5926 5358 9793 }
LuaTeX error [\directlua]:1: invalid escape sequence near '\s'. ...\c_pi_fp { 3.141 5926 5358 9793 }
Missing number, treated as zero. ...\c_pi_fp { 3.141 5926 5358 9793 }
Undefined control sequence. ...one_degree_fp { 0.0 1745 3292 5199 4330 }
Undefined control sequence. ...one_degree_fp { 0.0 1745 3292 5199 4330 }
LuaTeX error [\directlua]:1: invalid escape sequence near '\s'. ...one_degree_fp { 0.0 1745 3292 5199 4330 }
Missing number, treated as zero. ...one_degree_fp { 0.0 1745 3292 5199 4330 }
Undefined control sequence. { \i }
Undefined control sequence. { \i }
LuaTeX error [\directlua]:1: invalid escape sequence near '\i'. { \i }
Missing number, treated as zero. { \i }
Undefined control sequence. { \q_recursion_tail }
Undefined control sequence. { \q_recursion_tail }
LuaTeX error [\directlua]:1: invalid escape sequence near '\q'. { \q_recursion_tail }
Missing number, treated as zero. { \q_recursion_tail }
Undefined control sequence. { \q_recursion_tail }
Undefined control sequence. { \q_recursion_tail }
LuaTeX error [\directlua]:1: invalid escape sequence near '\q'. { \q_recursion_tail }
Missing number, treated as zero. { \q_recursion_tail }
Undefined control sequence. { \q_recursion_tail }
Undefined control sequence. { \q_recursion_tail }
LuaTeX error [\directlua]:1: invalid escape sequence near '\q'. { \q_recursion_tail }
Missing number, treated as zero. { \q_recursion_tail }
Undefined control sequence. { \q_recursion_tail }
Undefined control sequence. { \q_recursion_tail }
LuaTeX error [\directlua]:1: invalid escape sequence near '\q'. { \q_recursion_tail }
Missing number, treated as zero. { \q_recursion_tail }
Undefined control sequence. { \textsigma }
```

Comment: It looks to me like you've installed the packages in 'non-Admin' mode: run the update wizard without selecting the Admin version.

Comment: Thanks, that helped! I removed and installed MiKTeX again. This time for all users and everything is fine again.